# Photon Emission by Massless Fermions and Direction of Motion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, collision, photon-emission, particle-detectors

In Peskin, a derivation about the radiated energy at low frequencies is given, as well as a derivation about the (mean) number of radiated photons. Both are found to depend on the differential intensity $\mathcal{I}(\textbf{v},\textbf{v}')$, which is given by (6.15)
$$\mathcal{I}(\textbf{v},\textbf{v}')=\int\frac{d\Omega_k}{4\pi}\bigg(\frac{2(1-\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{v}')}{(1-\hat{k}\cdot\textbf{v})(1-\hat{k}\cdot\textbf{v}')}-\frac{m^2/E^2}{(1-\hat{k}\cdot\textbf{v})^2}-\frac{m^2/E^2}{(1-\hat{k}\cdot\textbf{v}')^2}\bigg)$$
where $\textbf{v}$ and $\textbf{v}'$ are the initial and final velocities of the emitting fermion.

If one tries to take the massless limit, i.e. the limit in which a massless fermion emits a photon, then the peaks in eq. (6.15) become infinitely large. The divergence is associated with the direction of the motion of the emitted photon being parallel to the direction of the initial/final fermion's momentum.

Does that mean that a photon being emitted by a massless fermion can not have direction of motion parallel to the emitting particle? Or does it have to do with the fact that it is not possible for a detector to detect two particles moving at the same direction (if something like this is true)?

Comment: What are the v and v' variables?  I found the formula here http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~gengb/200923/Peskin,%20An%20Introduction%20to%20Quantum%20Field%20Theory.pdf and it seems they are the velocities of the charged fermion  before and after the bremsstrahlung  emission of the particle. page 181. Are you aware the a zero mass particle can only move with the velocity of light?

Comment: Hi @annav. Yes, I forgot to mention that v and v' are the velocity vectors corresponding to the velocities of the initial and final charged fermions. What I am curious about is what happens at the limit in which $|\textbf{v}|\rightarrow1$? By observing equation (6.15), we can see that the probability of the emission, as well as the radiated energy, diverge when the fermions become massless. I was looking for an explanation on that. A physical interpretation of some sort... Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think that charged fermions with mass zero can happen only before the electroweak breaking anyway.https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154735/are-all-fermions-massless-at-high-temperatures

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wasn't looking for the cases in which the phenomenon I describe is physically realisable (Sorry if I missguided you with the way I formed the question). What I was asking I guess is "What does the divergence means in the radiated energy and in the probability??" and whether or not it is some sort of criterion for us to say that "there can not exist emission whose direction is parallel to the emitting particle"...

Comment: Well, I am just commenting, not answering.In any case the formula is derived with the classical case and Peskin has a lot of limitations for the formula in his book.